# Service to organize user stories

Tags: agile, scrum, user-stories

Does anybody know a good web service, where I can write and modify user stories with other people?
I've used Google's Wave. But as of 2012 Google did close this project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some options:

- [Asana](http://asana.com/) (This is what my team currently uses, and we love it.)
- [Pivotal](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/) (I've used this in the past. It is also great.)
- [VersionOne](http://www.versionone.com/) (Good if you are doing Agile in an enterprise environment.)
- [Trello](https://trello.com/) (Spolsky's new endeavor. I know several people who swear by it.)
- [Lean-To](http://lean-to.com/) (From the good folks at Refactr)
- [Mingle](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/mingle-agile-project-management) (From the Thoughtworks guys)
- [Skinnyboard](https://www.skinnyboard.com/user_session/new) (Clean and minimal)
- [Agilebuddy](http://www.agilebuddy.com/) (I've heard good things about this.)
- [ScrumPad](http://www.scrumpad.pro/) (Looks promising)

Features and cost vary, so you'll have to do a bit of comparison shopping. That said, don't rule out index cards if your team is co-located.

Comment: Great list, Trello is my favourite at the moment. With the 'Scrum for Trello' Chrome extension, it's even better and more relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Well, [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview) and [Pivotal Tracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/) are widely used products that can be used for both the actual Agile process management and for User Stories writing/managing/grooming.

Both are designed to be shared by a team and offer a hosted version at a very reasonable price.

My personal preference after using both for a number of projects is Jira because of its much higher flexibility in terms of configuration (process and story templates & fields), but Pivotal Tracker is pretty capable and simpler as well.

- Ed Y

Answer (score 0):

And what about [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Any sharing system is good. Google docs is one. Evernote is another. Dropbox works wonderfully as well. You may also go with something like github, and gain version management. Nobody said VCS systems are for code only.

Answer (score 0):

I also used Wave for this purpose. Although its not as good as Wave, the two tools that I play with these days are the new [Google hangout](https://plus.google.com/hangouts) which allows the sharing of windows/screen and/or pivotal tracker which has real-time push updates to stories. Between the two its almost as good as Google Wave.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com) you get a wiki and all Google Docs.
Take a look also at the template gallery.

I think also [Trello](https://trello.com/) is a good tool to share user story (it also update all clients in real time).